# How to fix the error in v-model rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following fragments in my `index.blade.php`:

*The `content` section:*

```
.
.
.
<div class="col-12 col-md-12 mb-3">
    <label for="attachment" text-muted">Attachment</label>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
            <b-form-file
                ref="attachment"
                id="attachment"
                v-model.trim="$v.feedback.upload.attachment.$model"
                placeholder="Click to upload..."
            ></b-form-file>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
.
.
.
```

*The `script` section:*

```
.
.
.
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            'feedback': { 'upload': {'attachment': null} }
        }
   }
})
.
.
.
```

Everytime I try to load the page, it caused this error as below:

*[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: $v.feedback.upload is undefined"
(found in Root)*

I would like to ask what caused the above error because when I commented the `v-model.trim="$v.feedback.upload.attachment.$model"` line, everything loads fine.
Thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: I think it should be just `v-model.trim="feedback.upload.attachment"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just

```
 v-model.trim="feedback.upload.attachment"
```

*answer credited to [@Damon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9764412/damon)*